# Option of starting X-terminal or GUI at start up

Tags: 12.04

I would like the option of either choosing a terminal session (x) or bring up the whole GUI.  In version 10, one could move the mouse down to the bottom of the screen and select "X-Term", and log in from there.  The bulk of the GUI would not come up and you were left with a terminal session to execute.  Or, you could go back to normal.  Version 12.04 does not appear to have this option, or does it?

Answer (score 0):

You can start a terminal session by pressing Ctrl + Alt+ F1. Read more about it [here](http://linux.about.com/od/linux101/l/blnewbie5_1.htm).

Comment: Thank you very much.  However, the the Ctrl+Alt+F1 doesn't pull up the same X terminal that was available at Log in under release 10.  There is something missing.